# what does "??" mean in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, nullable

I am a student studying about mvvm.

And I saw some code.

so what does "??" mean in kotlin.

I searched for this but I couldn't find it.

How can I fix it if I'm wrong? -> (s.toString ?? "")

**1.**

```
fun wrap(a: Int?): Int?? {
    return a
}

fun desc(a: Int??) {
    if (a == null) {
        println("None")
    } else {
        if (a == null) {
            println("Some(None)")
        } else {
            println("Some(Some($a))")
        }
    }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val a: Int?? = wrap(null)
    desc(a) 
}
```

---

**2.**

```
<layout/>
    <data>
        <variable>
            name="signid"
            type="SignidViewModel" />
    </data>

    <EditText
        android:onTextChanged='@{(s,start,end,before) -> signid.Check_ID(s.toString ?? "")}' />
</layout>
```

Comment: `?` mean that if `this` particular value is null, do **not** use it and skip it, hence no crash due to NPE. `!!` mean that if `this` particular value is null, throw NPE, hence crashing the code(excluding exception handling). How you want to use null safety in Kotlin is up to you. But I have not seen a reason to use `!!`. Also, please look for official documentation which most probably going to answer your question. And I don't know how you could not find anything about Kotlin null safety. [Official doc clearly explains everything](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The null safety operator is defined as '?' in kotlin. If you are talking about null-aware operator in dart then in that case two question marks is used. The null-awareness in kotlin is achieved making null-safe to variable as

> val testString:String?

In dart (or any other language) this is called for the null check as

> x=y ?? z

meaning, assing y to x until y is not null, else z

Answer (score 4):

Looks like some redundant code. You can safely remove the second question mark

```
fun wrap(a: Int?): Int? {
    return a
}

fun desc(a: Int?) {
    if (a == null) {
        println("None")
    } else {
        if (a == null) {
            println("Some(None)")
        } else {
            println("Some(Some($a))")
        }
    }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val a: Int? = wrap(null)
    desc(a)
}
```

in the second case you have to use `?:` operator instead of `??`

```
<layout/>
    <data>
        <variable>
            name="signid"
            type="SignidViewModel" />
    </data>

    <EditText
        android:onTextChanged='@{(s,start,end,before) -> signid.Check_ID(s.toString ?: "")}' />
</layout>
```

`val s = string ?: ""` means

```
if (string != null) {
    val s = string
} else {
    val s = ""
}
```

Comment: consider adding to your answer what the `?` operator does, too :)

Answer (score 0):

Here you can use ?(null safety operator).If for some reason your value is getting null it is not going to be crashed.

```
fun wrap(a: Int?): Int? {
    return a
}

fun desc(a: Int?) {
    if (a == null) {
        println("None")
    } else {
        if (a == null) {
            println("Some(None)")
        } else {
            println("Some(Some($a))")
        }
    }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val a: Int? = wrap(null)
    desc(a)
}
```

so please use it like this.and let me know

Comment: Your wrap function is pointless, it's equivalent to `val a: Int? = null`.